# Background Task still with cache? Or SO Team Find a Problem

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, background

I am about to use what Jeff post about [Easy Background Task in Asp.Net](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/). I want to know if SO still use it or they found a Problem with the solution.

Thanks

Comment: Since they are now on multiple web servers, I assume they at least need to limit it to one server (so they don't step on each other's toes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked in UserVoice and Jeff answer me that they use "HTTP request service".